# CSS выровнять нижний край строки по одной линии во всех ячейках таблицы при разной высоте шрифта

Tags: css

Гуру CSS помогите! Как выровнять нижний край строки по одной линии во всех ячейках таблицы при разной высоте шрифта? Нужно именно в **table** не **div**

```css
.class-all {
  width: 100%;
}

.class-one {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.class-two {
  font-size: 13px;
}

.class-three {
  font-size: 36px;
}
```

```html
<table class="class-all">
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td class="class-one">AAA</td>
  <td class="class-two">00:00:00 UTC+0</td>
  <td class="class-three">5.5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `table td { text-align: end; vertical-align: bottom; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот сам решил, может кому понадобится, добавил класс **class-row** для строки

```css
.class-all{
    width: 100%;
}
.class-row {
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.class-one {
  font-size: 28px;
}

.class-two {
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: right;
}

.class-three {
  font-size: 36px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table class="class-all">
<tbody>
<tr class="class-row">
  <td class="class-one">AAA</td>
  <td class="class-two">00:00:00 UTC+0</td>
  <td class="class-three">5.5</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```